# Change uploadify image after upload

Tags: javascript, uploadify, image-uploading

I use uploadify to upload an image. The upload button is a camera image (camera.png), but when selecting an image, and when upload is successful, the upload button image is another image (success.png).

Here is the used javascript code:

```
$('#form-add-post-image').uploadify({
    'swf':         'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader':    'uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'buttonImage': 'uploadify/camera.png',
    'width':       128,
    'height':      128,
    'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response){
        $(this).uploadify('settings', 'buttonImage', 'uploadify/success.png');
    }
});
```

But, this doesn't work, and the console gives this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: settingValue is not defined`.

Any idea?

And what `Uncaught ReferenceError: settingValue is not defined` means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js I wanted also to change the upload image after the image is uploaded,
a simple solution that I found was add the hideButton property to my uploadify settings

`'hideButton': 'true',`

and you wont have to load the browse image from uploadify simply load it from your css

```
    #your_uploadify_id{
    background: url(browse.png) no-repeat;
}
```

then in onComplete load the new image to your css:

```
'onComplete'  : function(){
$("#browes_pictureUploader").css({'background-image':'url(change_picture.png)'});
}
```

Comment: Thank you talsibony for your answer. But I don't understand... What is `hideButton` property? This is not available in uploadify documentation http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Comment: 'hideButton': 'true', its uploadify property

my uploadify version is jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js this version include this property